# PRISM navigation InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

When I navigate back to the same view, *OnNavigatedTo(..)* is not called.
In my debug window, I get following error:

> *A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll*

How can I get more debug information? I want to know where PRISM fails..

I can not find out where the error occurs, because the viewmodel and view are already (correctly) created. I'm just navigating back to it.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample reproducing the issue you are describing? It will help to identify the issue and to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Its hard, I can't take a piece out of my production application. It also uses Devexpress libraries, so you wouldn't be able to compile it locally. I just want to know if it's possible to view the complete stacktrace of that exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which exceptions to break on in the **Exception Settings** tab while debugging. For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx.

In your case, you would need to enable `System.InvalidOperationException` under **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**.